# Unable to locate element by ID when I use Junit

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0), in Windows 8.1. I have a selenium(V 2.53) code which is working fine.

```
f.get("https://mail.yahoo.com");
f.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("jj%jo.com");

WebElement element = f.findElement(By.id("login-username"));
String text = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(text);
```

However, when I add Junit v4.12 and TestNG in Project>BuildPath the code is unable to locate the element.

```
@Test
public void testFindUsername(){
    f.findElement(By.id("login-username")).click();
    f.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("jsnow@go.com");
}
```

> Error: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"login-username"}
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>
> http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

If anyone else had this issue, kindly let us know the solution.

Thank You

Comment: make some wait after get the url

Comment: Got it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateGuest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = getGuestName();
        printName(name);
    }

    public static String getGuestName() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        String name = in.next();
        in.close();
        return name;
    }

    public static void printName(String name) {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + name);
    }

}
```